# Aggregate Contributions Reports and fiscal years (and households, too)

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

We have a client with a July 1 to June 30 fiscal year. To filter by a timeframe, the CiviReport system for aggregate contributions insists on grouping by a time period, which is NOT a fiscal year (Year, month, week, or day). If I filter by an aggregate amount, it then it does not include those who gave less in a calendar year even if they gave the required amount in a fiscal year. (It also displays them in separate lines.) How can I get true aggregate reporting in the timeframe I require?

ALSO: Any way to get this to work on the HOUSEHOLD level? I really need to group giving by any member of a household together without requiring people to enter gifts only to the household.

Thank you!

P.S. We need to upgrade, so these comments are for version 4.4.6

Answer (score 2):

I believe this extension will provide the aggregation you're looking for: https://civicrm.org/extensions/aggregate-household-contributions-report

I'm also the main person working on CRM-16195 that Lobo mentioned - I'm trying hard to make time for this (unpaid) work to get it into 4.7, but time is tight!  However, your use case is listed on our notes sheet: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Notepad+for+CRM-16195

Comment: It took my a while, but I managed to upgrade to the latest version of CiviCRM and the install the extension you mention.I had some trouble getting this installed in report templates, but now it's working and clearly heading towards what I needed. Now that I managed it, unfortunately, I'm getting all results from all time no matter what the many filters are set to. I do not see the "Determine aggregate column values" filter twomice mentions in his readme. (I also am a bit confused by multiple date and campaign filters (qualifying vs those without qualifying).

Comment: The extension @Jon-G mentions does seem to work, but it has a CSS/javascript bug of some sort. In Firefox I turned off the application of CSS since I had a flash of unstyled content which seemed to show those "aggregate Column Values" checkboxes. Lo-and-behold the checkboxes were there, I was able to check one, and the results changed. (I have yet to analyze the results, but the matched records came WAY down, as they should have!) Now someone needs to patch this extension. Am I the only one trying to use this, or has the CSS changed, or??

Answer (score 1):

This issue (which is work being done for 4.7) might help address part of your problem:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16195

however the underlying grouping that civicrm uses (which it actually punts to mysql grouping) might not match your fiscal year requirement and you might need to adopt a different approach